# Should the POSIX 'CLOCK_REALTIME' clock be referenced to the UTC epoch?

Tags: c, time, posix

I'm using the POSIX clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &curr_time) to get the current time of the CLOCK_REALTIME clock. I understand the difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC. However, what I don't know is the epoch associated with CLOCK_REALTIME.

My first guess was that it would be the elapsed seconds/nanoseconds since the UTC epoch. However, the value that I'm getting is ~180000 seconds which is ~50 hours. Obviously not the time elapsed since the UTC epoch.

So my question: what is CLOCK_REALTIME referenced against? Reboot? Platform specfic? UTC and I'm just doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Show us the code you used, `CLOCK_REALTIME` should be (today) in the order of one billion and a half (got 1491312994 some minutes ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLOCK_REALTIME is tied to the Unix epoch ("UTC epoch" is the same thing but is not the correct way to name it.  It's just the Unix epoch in the UTC timezone).

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    printf("%ld\n", ts.tv_sec);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [POSIX specification for `clock_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) defines the zero point for `CLOCK_REALTIME` as "the Epoch":

> All implementations shall support a `clock_id` of `CLOCK_REALTIME` as defined in `<time.h>`. This clock represents the clock measuring real time for the system. For this clock, the values returned by `clock_gettime()` and specified by `clock_settime()` represent the amount of time (in seconds and nanoseconds) since the Epoch.

It defines the term "the Epoch" in its ["General Concepts" chapter, section 4.16](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16):

> A Coordinated Universal Time name (specified in terms of seconds (tm_sec), minutes (tm_min), hours (tm_hour), days since January 1 of the year (tm_yday), and calendar year minus 1900 (tm_year)) is related to a time represented as seconds since the Epoch, according to the expression below.
>
> If the year is <1970 or the value is negative, the relationship is undefined. If the year is >=1970 and the value is non-negative, the value is related to a Coordinated Universal Time name according to the C-language expression, where tm_sec, tm_min, tm_hour, tm_yday, and tm_year are all integer types:
>
> ```
> tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
>     (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
>     ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
> ```

If you put that expression on one side of an equation, and zero on the other, and add in the usual constraints on the range of day-of-year, hour, minute, second, you find that "the Epoch" corresponds to ISO calendar date 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.  Why they don't just say that, I don't know.

---

The phenomenon you observed, where `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)` produced a value of roughly 50 hours since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, is accounted for in the very next sentence of POSIX chapter 4:

> The relationship between the actual time of day and the current value for seconds since the Epoch is unspecified.

Which is to say, POSIX does not require your computer's clock to be accurate.